# How to set leftmargin when using the enumerate package?

Tags: lists, indentation

Is it possible to set the `leftmargin` length when using the `enumerate` package? I'd like to limit the effect of `leftmargin` to a single environment invokation only and not set it globally.

Comment: I recommend the package `enumitem`. It is more flexible. Or do you stand on `enumerate`?

Comment: @Marco: Nope, I can switch packages if necessary. Could you give your comment as an answer instead so I can vote it up and accept as answer?

Comment: Can someone provide a work around with `enumerate` package? I want to do the same thing and I am stuck with this package.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I recommend the package `enumitem`. Here you can set `leftmargin` local.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{enumitem,showframe}

 \begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2cm]
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1cm]
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \asbuk doesn't work in `enumitem`, for some reason... Have to use `enumerate`

Comment: add `[leftmargin=1cm]` follow `\begin{enumerate}` does NOT work for me, but add `[\hspace{1pt}(1)]` works.

Answer (score 7):

If you must use `enumerate`, you can start the optional argument of the enumerated list with an `\hspace` to push the whole list farther to the right:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}

\begin{document}

Some text before the list.
\begin{enumerate}[\hspace{18pt}(P1)]
\item Some text.
\item Some text that goes onto two lines, so you can see where the second line will be aligned.
\item An equation:
\begin{equation}
1+1=2.
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
Some text after the list.

\end{document}
```

I don't know of a better way to do this with `enumerate`.

Comment: This is the better solution when one works with beamer, because the enumitem package is not suitable with it, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52299/65333 . Thank you for your answer.

Comment: thank you! I was desperatly searching for a way to do it without using enumitem!