# Dealing with long description environment items

Tags: beamer, lists, description

I have quite a lot of description environments in Beamer that are having both long and short items, leading to an output like

```
veryverylongitem description 1
    shortitem description 2
```

which is not really great.

So I'm trying to put labels and descriptions on different lines, in something like

```
veryverylongitem
            description 1
shortitem
            description 2
```

I've tried two things for that:

```
\let\origdescription\description
\renewenvironment{description}{
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}
\origdescription
\setlength{\itemindent}{0em}
\setlength{\labelsep}{\textwidth}
}
{\endlist}
```

which seem to do what I'd like, except that things are completely glitchy when using two nested description environment

On another hand, puting something like

```
\begin{description}
\item[veryveryveryverylongitem]\hfill\\
     description 1
\item[shortitem]\hfill\\
     description 2
\end{description}
```

will do the job perfectly, except that I can't find a way to do renew the item command so that the hfill would applied document-wide.

Is there other way to deal with long description, or have I done something wrong in the two solutions ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using the `enumitem` package with `beamer` is *not* a good idea; for example, just by loading `enumitem`, the default beamer font and color specifications for `description` are lost; moreover `\setbeamercolor` and `\setbeamerfont` will have no effect on `description item`; even worst, the enumitem package will also interfere with the `beamer`  layout for `itemize` and `enumerate`; in fact, it will produce errors for the `enumerate` environment (See example at the bottom).

In the following example I defined a `Ldescription` environment based on the beamer definition of standard `description`; since the new definition follows the "beamer way", it will behave as expected (it's overaly aware, for exampe, and respects the color and font templates) and will give you the desired layout (feel free to adjust the lengths according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\Ldescription{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\beamer@testforospec}{\beamer@descdefault\beamer@descriptionwidth\@@Ldescription}%
}

\def\beamer@testforospec[{\@ifnextchar<{\beamer@scandefaultospec[}{\@Ldescription[}}%

\def\beamer@scandefaultospec[#1]{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}\Ldescription}

\def\@Ldescription[#1]{%
\setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\def\insertdescriptionitem{#1}
  \usebeamertemplate**{description item}}%
\beamer@descdefault\wd\beamer@tempbox\@@description%
}%

\def\@@Ldescription{%
  \beamer@descdefault35pt%
  \list
  {}
  {\labelwidth\beamer@descdefault\leftmargin2.8em\let\makelabel\beamer@Ldescriptionitem}%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}

\def\endLdescription{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\endlist}
\long\def\beamer@Ldescriptionitem#1{%
  \def\insertdescriptionitem{#1}%
  \hspace\labelsep{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\labelsep\relax}{%
        \usebeamertemplate**{description item}%
    }}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{Ldescription}
\item<1->[very very very very long item] \lipsum[2]
\item<2,4>[short titem] description 2
\item<3->[another very very very very long item] description 3
\item<4->[short item] description 4
\end{Ldescription}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the fourth frame:

[image]

### Why enumitem shouln't be used with beamer

Processing the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{enumitem}

\setbeamercolor{description item}{fg=olive!80!black}
\setbeamerfont{description item}{size=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{description}
\item[item] description
\end{description}
\begin{itemize}
\item description
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

produces the following (expected) output:

[image]

Now uncomment-out the line loading `enumitem`. reprocess and now you'll get the following undesired result:

[image]

Now, try this simple document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and you'll receive:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\labelenumi ->{
               \labelenumi }
l.10 \end{frame}
                
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The moral is clear: `enumitem` and `beamer`a are incompatible. Perhaps using the `loadonly` package option to create own lists could be safe:

```
\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}
```

Comment: @cyberSingularity No problem; in fact, I appreciate your comment; I will take a closer look (I only used the 1pt as a quick dirty workaround) and let you know when I find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @cyberSingularity I updated my answer; I hope this time the overfull boxes disappear. Please let me know if the new version works as expected.

Comment: They do indeed disappear. Am I right in thinking that the main change is the `\beamer@descdefault` value?

Comment: @cyberSingularity yes, you are right.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I have posted a follow-up question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76481/17427 and will delete my comments from here. Thanks!

Comment: @cyberSingularity OK.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the great [enumitem](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package for this. It's already defined as a style under the descriptions class with `nextline`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
\item<1->[veryveryveryverylongitem] description 1
\item<2-3>[shortitem] description 2
\item<3->[shortitem2] description 3
\item<4->[shortitem3] description 4
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the overlay specification declaration one can use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
\item[veryveryveryverylongitem] description 1
\item[shortitem] description 2
\item[shortitem] description 2
\item[shortitem] description 2
\end{description}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{description}[style=nextline]
\item[Any overlay?] No overlay!
\item[Yes] I see them all...
\item[Can make the command] {\verb|\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}|}
\item[something] shorter
\end{description}           
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

thanks to Marco Daniel, enumitem seems to be not that innocent to use in beamer. Also cmhughes' comment can be another option.

Comment: This solution isn't well. `enumitem` destroys the overlay specification of beamer. (Sorry)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel No problem at all. I tried with a few and it works as usual (added a few in the example). Care to expand on that?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer

Comment: you can use `\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}` and then create your own list- all of the existing lists (`itemize`, `enumerate`, `description`) are left alone

Comment: @MarcoDaniel They don't seem to be destroying but of course better to keep in my mind. I tried some examples but I can't say that I have a serious problem.

Comment: @cmhughes Indeed that's a sensible way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Just loading `enumitem` will change the layout for the `description` environment defined by `beamer` (for example, it annihilates the color specifications of the desciption items).