# List with arrows instead of bullets

Tags: lists, arrows, itemize, enumitem

I want a bullet list with arrows instead of bullets, like:

```
=> Line 1
=> Line 2
```

I tried this, but it returned some error:

```
\begin{itemize}{labelitemi}{$\Rightarrow$}[leftmargin=1em]
 \item Line 1
 \item Line 2
\end{itemize}
```

(I took the code from [here](http://hapticity.net/2007/03/23/latex-itemize-bullet-characters/))
It should be simple, but I couldn't figure it out from enumitem's manual. How do I go about this?

Comment: What's the error? Also, please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the question you're linking to is meaning another syntax, but this works :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}%[leftmargin=1em]
  \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\Rightarrow$}
 \item Line 1
 \item Line 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why isn't that working when using beamer?

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the provided answers, if you use `enumitem` package, instead of redefining the label for all your `itemize` environments, you can define a new `arrowlist` environment which uses arrows instead of bullets, leaving the standard `itemize` unnaffected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{arrowlist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[arrowlist]{label=$\Rightarrow$}

\begin{document}

\begin{arrowlist}
\item Line 1
\item Line 2
\end{arrowlist}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Note that you should avoid using `enumitem` along with `beamer`. If you just want to define a new list (like here) you might use `\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52274/dealing-with-long-description-environment-items).

Answer (score 6):

```
 \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\Rightarrow$}
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to use enumerate, unlike enumitem, this works also with the beamer package

```
\begin{enumerate}[$\Rightarrow$]
 \item 
    .
    .
    .
  \item
\end{enumerate}
```