# How to make L-shaped arrow in text?

Tags: arrows

I am wondering if it is possible to insert L-shaped within a text as a bullet-point.

[image: L-shaped arrow]

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: See [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14) and [List with arrows instead of bullets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84936). `mathabx` contains such a glyph; I'm sure there are others too.

Comment: if the glyph in `mathabx` is used, it might also be helpful to look at [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,mathabx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[$\drsh$]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

See [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/15925) to locate the symbol and the use `enumitem` to set this up in an itemize:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label=\( \drsh \)]
\item An item.
\item Another item.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The closes L-shaped arrow of Zapf Dingbats (see [psnfss2e](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf)) and the use as bullet point in an `itemize` list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{229}]
\item \lipsum[75]
\item \lipsum[101]
\item \lipsum[103]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\myarrow}{\tikz\draw[thick,magenta,-latex] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1.5ex) -- +(2.5ex,0);}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\myarrow]
\item \lipsum[75]
\item \lipsum[101]
\item \lipsum[103]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]