# List with arrows in two different directions

Tags: enumerate, indentation, itemize, arrows, paragraphs

The goal is to reproduce this formatting in LaTex (in proving *if and only if*):

[image]

where **the entire paragraph is indented except the arrows**. Additionally, **two arrows are pointing to different directions**.

Closest that I have tried: [List with arrows instead of bullets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84936/list-with-arrows-instead-of-bullets) where JLDiaz defined a new `arrowlist` environment. However, under this setting, arrows all have the same direction.

Image source: http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item[$\Rightarrow$] Given a satisying question that does not force the ones
 answering it to type in texts from a screen shot.
 \item[$\Leftarrow$] Given a set of input parameters satisying some strange
 conditions one will always find someone.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Such an elegent solution! Thanks!