# Beamer: problem showing description item

Tags: beamer, description

I'm trying to put a `description` environment with some data in my presentation. But `pdflatex` compiles it without showing the part in `[]` of `\item`.

Minimal reproducing example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{description}
        \item[equ] lorem
        \item[$p = -\left(1 + \left(\dfrac{k}{k_g}\right)^2\right)$] ipsum.
    \end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

I've found that this is a problem with the color theme: `orchid`. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble?

Comment: I found that it didn't work, same problems as [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52299/9790).

Comment: The `Bergen` theme loads `\usecolortheme{orchid}` and `\useinnertheme{inmargin}`, and it seems to be the combination of the two that causes the issue (removing `\usecolortheme{orchid}` from your MWE has no improvement). The description headings are there but they are in white, the same as the background colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inheritance of colors in beamer isn't easy to follow but imho

```
\setbeamercolor{item}{parent=structure}
```

is the best to get around the problem.