# Align sentences beneath each other. Like ruler in word!

Tags: rules, columns, notes, definition

Essentially, I want to be able align the non-bold sentences underneath each other. In word I would use a ruler. As you would if you ignored all the underlines

**Canonical Ensemble:** System with fixed particle number, volume and temperature.
__________________(Microcanonical ensemble has fixed energy instead of temperature!)

Comment: That looks like a definition with explanation: is there only one or will it be a list? Please provide some context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways: with a `description` environment + adjusted parameters, and one with the `linegoal` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\begin{description}[font = \sffamily\bfseries, leftmargin=\widthof{\bfseries Canonical Ensemble:\hskip\labelsep}]
\item[Canonical Ensemble:]System with fixed particle number, volume and temperature.\\ (Microcanonical ensemble has fixed energy instead of temperature!)
\end{description}
\vskip 1cm

\noindent\textbf{Canonical Ensemble:}\enspace\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{System with fixed particle number, volume and temperature.\\ (Microcanonical ensemble has fixed energy instead of temperature!)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the `linegoal`solution is the one which fits the description of the desired function the most.

Comment: This works amazingly!

Answer (score 5):

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[labelwidth=*, widest]
        \item[\textbf{Canonical}] Something \\something
        \item[\textbf{fooo}] bar
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

With this the next line is indented

[image]

But if this is used to provide some kind of glossary, there are special packages for this.

Comment: How can I get it to align with the rest of my text? 
I now find that "Canonical" ends up in the margins.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28107/how-to-set-leftmargin-when-using-the-enumerate-package

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I recommend the method suggested by Sango, but you can also do it like this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth} p{0.6\textwidth}}
\textbf{Canonical Ensemble:} & System with fixed particle number, volume and temperature.
   Microcanonical ensemble has fixed energy instead of temperature!
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `eqlist` or `desclist`:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqlist}   %                  <-- for solution 1 
\usepackage{desclist} %                  <-- for  solution 2 
\usepackage{geometry,parskip,lipsum} % irrelevants for the question 
\begin{document}

\lipsum[3][1-7] % Only dummy text 

% Solution 1
\begin{eqlist} % optionally [\setlength\labelsep{...}]

\item[\bfseries Canonical Ensemble:] System with fixed particle number, volume and temperature.\\ (Microcanonical ensemble has fixed energy instead of temperature!) 
\item[\bfseries Ensemble Telúrico:] Supposed musical group of the comedy-musical group Les Luthiers that interpret the music of the supposed composer Johann Sebastian Mastropiero. 
\end{eqlist}

\lipsum[3][1-7] % More dummy text 

% Solution 2
\begin{desclist}{\hskip14em}{:\qquad}[\bfseries Canonical Ensemble]
\item[\bfseries Canonical Ensemble] System with fixed particle number, volume and temperature.\\ (Microcanonical ensemble has fixed energy instead of temperature!) 
\item[\bfseries Ensemble Telúrico] Supposed musical group of the comedy-musical group Les Luthiers that interpret the music of the supposed composer Johann Sebastian Mastropiero. 
\end{desclist}

\lipsum[3][1-7] % Dummy text  again
\end{document}
```

Similarly with `\usepackage{expdlist}`  you can use the same items of "Solution 1" but in a extended `description` list that allow options, in this way:

```
\begin{description}[\setlabelphantom{Canonical Ensemble:}]
\item ...
\end{description}
```

Or you can use use `tabto,` making a `\hangindent` as long as the `\tab`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto,parskip}   
\TabPositions{14em,16em} 
\begin{document}
{\bfseries Canonical Ensemble:} \tab\hangindent14em  System with fixed
particle number, volume and temperature.\\ (Microcanonical ensemble 
has fixed energy instead of temperature!) 

{\bfseries Ensemble Telúrico:}\tab\hangindent14em  Supposed musical
group of the comedy-musical group Les Luthiers that interpret the 
 music of the supposed composer Johann Sebastian Mastropiero.
```

Although the output is apparently similar, in this case is not at all equivalent to a list, so in many different situations your mileage will vary with one or another type of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Did anyone say `\phantom`? Because you can use `\phantom` here!

```
Lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.

\phantom{Lorem} ipsum ipsum est!
```

[image: screenshot of an example]