# Block-wise indented paragraph with title on left-side margin

Tags: paragraphs

I am quite new in using LaTeX and need to structure my paper outline as depicted in the image. Would anybody be able to tell me how this is could be done in LaTeX? I'd appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It would be very helpful to know what document class you intend to use -- the answer could be different depending on that choice.  [This recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527391/579) has answers that follow the format you show; perhaps it can help.

Comment: This remind me on `description` list. With use of `enumitem` package you can simply define desired layout.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you for linking the answer! That is precisely what I intend to do. And Zarko thank you for your reply as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength\LW
\settowidth{\LW}{\textbf{Chapter 33}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=\LW,labelsep=1em,
                        leftmargin=\dimexpr\LW+1em]
\item[Chapter 1]    \lipsum[66]
\item[Chapter 22]    \lipsum[77]
    \end{description}
\end{document}
˙``
gives

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuQsb.png
```

Comment: Great! Many thanks, Zarko!