# Best way to write title paragraphs in LaTeX

Tags: sectioning, formatting, paragraphs

I was trying to emulate the style found in some math textbooks of having titled paragraphs through a sidebar of sorts, and i was wondering what the best way to go about it was. For now, i am (ab?)using the `itemize` environment, by changing item names at will, i.e.

```latex
\begin{itemize}
  \item[Encryption] \textit{Encrypting} means you care about the message's...
  \item[Signing] When you sign a message...
\end{itemize}
```

[image: example output of my approach]

As you can see, it "works", as long as the paragraph title is not too long, but it does get cumbersome as the paragraphs get longer, and in particular i can't see myself writing a whole document like this (this example was more of a paragraph within a larger document.

Is there an easier way to get this effect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `titlesec` can do that for you. The manual has just such an example on p. 22.

Comment: That looks like a very useful tool, i'll look more into it. Thank you for replying this fast!

Comment: What if you just change the two  `itemize` keys  by `description`? If you are no are not happy  with this new format, see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527503/11604).

Comment: You could use paracol with the title in one column and the text in the other.  If you don't know the widths a priori, you might try ltxtable (not sure if the paragraphs will break across pages).